# Change menu color when scrolled past certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, background-color, typeerror

I'm trying to make my menu, that sticks on the top of the page, to change color when I passed scrolling a certain div.

I guess the problem lies in this line: `var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();`
Because I get the error from chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` Whats wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav {
            background-color:transparent;
            color:#fff;
            transition: all 0.25s ease;
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            width:100%;
            background-color:#ccc;
            padding:1em;
        }

        .nav.past-main {
            background-color:#fff;
            color:#444;
        }

        #main {
            height:500px;
            background-color:red;
        }

        #below-main {
            height:1000px;
            background-color:#eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();

        $(window).on('scroll',function(){
            stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
            if (stop > mainbottom) {
                $('.nav').addClass('past-main');
            }
            else {
                $('.nav').removeClass('past-main');
            }
        });
    </script>

    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">#main</div>
    <div id="below-main">#below-main</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the code from here: http://codepen.io/taylorleejones/pen/KJsvz?editors=011 but doesn't seem to work for me
Thanks! :)

Comment: The code works fine on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nSA37/. Are you sure the path to jQuery in your code is correct? Check the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is running before the DOM elements that it makes use of are rendered. Things like `#main` don't exist yet because your code is being executed as soon as it's parsed by the browser (unless you specifically ask it to wait) and what you are trying to access is `undefined`. Move the `script` tags in the body to the bottom of the body or use one of the many methods for delaying execution until the DOM loads.

```
<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">#main</div>
    <div id="below-main">#below-main</div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            //your code
            var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();

            $(window).on('scroll',function(){

                stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
                if (stop > mainbottom) {
                    $('.nav').addClass('past-main');
                } else {
                    $('.nav').removeClass('past-main');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

or

```
$(document.ready(function() {
//your code
});
```

or

```
window.onload = function() {
//your code
};
```

Comment: The first 2 are identical, `$(function(){});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready();`. And be careful with `window.onload` vs `document.onload` as there are differences in when those events fire.